# s3 access denied issue across account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

I've complete export of csv files under diff time folder when they were exported

For example

```
s3:/mybucket/vloging/202302051000/export.csv
s3:/mybucket/vloging/202302050900/export.csv
s3:/mybucket/vloging/202302041800/export.csv
s3:/mybucket/vloging/202302041900/export.csv
```

And I've table created in Glue Catalog, which is pointing to always latest export

```
create external table demo (
id int,
name string,
location string
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/vloging/202302051000/'
```

when ever there is new export, I run `lambda` function to update table's location to latest export folder in `Glue`.

to update, I'm using this API

```
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/update_table.html
```

This `demo` table's access is given to user in another aws account, but whenever he tries to access in Aws Glue ETL job after table location update, gets s3 access denied error.

May I know please, after updating table using `Glue.Client.update_table(**kwargs)`, do I need to update something else also to avoid such error ?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: do you have any resource based policies to s3 ? can you paste the error msg.
If user is in another account how are you trying to access the resources in another account / is any role created ? Also if yes does it has necessary permissions to read s3 objects and etl.

Comment: @itshagunrathore permissions are already in place, the problem happens when new export is created and table points to new location, then user not able to access and shows s3 denied error

Comment: could you share your permission boundary / policy doc.

Comment: Access to objects in Amazon S3 is denied by default (yes, you know that). So, there must be _something_ that is giving the user access to the object -- either a Bucket Policy on the bucket or an IAM Policy on the user. (Actually, since it is cross-account, you will likely need _BOTH_). Please show us the policies that you believe should be granting access to this cross-account user. Don't worry that they could access the 'old' file -- please show us why you think they should be permitted to access the 'new' file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, we gave access to Glue table <<Demo>> via aws lake formation. Since he's trying to access glue table, then I'm wondering why s3 access denied error, even though permissions are in place  ? We want user to read new export file only via glue table, that's why we update glue table location to latest export directory.